# Google Cloud snapshot's boot issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

Hope all are safe and doing well.

I have few running servers on google cloud and for them, snapshots are scheduled on daily basis in an incremental way.

I am trying to create a new instance on a different VPC zone by using the same snapshots but it will be giving me an error.

For reference, I have added an attachment to this question.

Please help me to resolve this issue and thanks in advance.

[image: boot error]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have created a **[Snapshot with Application consistency(VSS)](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-windows-persistent-disk-snapshot)** enabled:

> When you create a VSS snapshot, Windows Server marks the volume in the
> snapshot as **read-only**. Any disks that you create from the VSS
> snapshot are also in read-only mode. So, the read-only flag on the new
> boot disk prevents the VM instance from booting correctly.

You can follow this documentation to resolve your issue [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-windows-persistent-disk-snapshot#read-only).

> If the disk you created from the VSS snapshot is a boot disk and you want to use it to boot a VM instance, you must temporarily attach the disk to a separate, existing VM instance. Once you complete the following steps, you can detach the disk from that existing VM instance and use it to boot a new VM instance.

Comment: Thanks, I will check and let you know